# Parsing a dynamic page with Perl and Gtk3::WebKit

Tags: perl, parsing, webkit, gtk3

I am using the Gtk3::WebKit to parse a website which loads content to itself with JavaScript. When the site is loaded it adds multiple divs with content to the DOM:

`<div class="product-card">...</div>`

How do I get this content with Gtk3::WebKit? How to get the nested tag's content? Is there a normal documentation about Gtk3::WebKit, because everything I've already seen is very poor documented.

Comment: Note: On Ubuntu 20.04, it seems the required package `gir1.2-webkit-3.0` has been deprecated, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1306824/156688) link and I am not able to install Gtk3::WebKit here..

Comment: Note: [Gtk3::WebKit2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Gtk3::WebKit2) provides updated WebKit2 bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using [Gtk3::WebKit2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Gtk3::WebKit2) :

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk3 -init;
use Gtk3::WebKit2;
use Gtk3::JavaScriptCore;

{
    my $url = 'https://metacpan.org/pod/Gtk3::WebKit2';
    my $window = Gtk3::Window->new('toplevel');
    $window->set_default_size(800, 600);
    $window->signal_connect(destroy => sub { Gtk3->main_quit() });
    my $ctx = Gtk3::WebKit2::WebContext::get_default();
    my $view = Gtk3::WebKit2::WebView->new_with_context($ctx);
    $view->signal_connect('load-changed', sub {
        my ($view, $load_event) = @_;
        if ($load_event eq 'finished') {
            run_javascript(
                $view,
                'document.getElementsByClassName("logged_out")[1].innerHTML;'
            );
        }
    });
    $view->load_uri($url);
    my $scrolls = Gtk3::ScrolledWindow->new();
    $scrolls->add($view);
    $window->add($scrolls);
    $window->show_all();
    Gtk3::main_iteration while Gtk3::events_pending;
    Gtk3->main;
}

sub run_javascript {
    my ($view, $javascript_string) = @_;

    my $done = 0;

    $view->run_javascript($javascript_string, undef, sub {
        my ($object, $result, $user_data) = @_;
        my $value = $view->run_javascript_finish($result)->get_js_value;
        say $value->to_string;
        $done = 1;
        return "ok";
    }, undef);

    Gtk3::main_iteration while Gtk3::events_pending and not $done;
}
```

**Output**:

```
<a href="" onclick="alert('Please sign in to add favorites'); return false" class="favorite highlight" title="Add to favorites">
<span>2</span> ++</a>
```

Comment: This is not what I've needed actually but it explains a lot. Can you suggest the manual?

Comment: Great that it helped you! I think the manual is [here](https://webkitgtk.org/) since the perl modules simply use [Glib::Object::Introspection](https://metacpan.org/pod/Glib::Object::Introspection) to dynamically create Perl bindings to the WebKitGTK C library. For example, the `$view->run_javascript_finish()` method is documented [here](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/unstable/WebKitWebView.html#webkit-web-view-run-javascript-finish)